# What does "no es posible jugar con la paciencia humana" mean in this context?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

In Anton Chejov's story *Un Hombre Irascible*, the narrator is interrupted by a woman when trying to measure a rare eclipse to predict the future. The woman says:

> —¿Por qué no me mira usted? —me susurra tiernamente al oído.

He replies:

> Esto es ya más que una burla. Convenid en que no es posible jugar con 
>   la paciencia humana. Si algo terrible sobreviene, no será por culpa mía.

I found that in another context it could mean "to try one's patience" but trying humanity's patience doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. It means something close to "test one's patient".

When the author says "la paciencia humana" he means "la paciencia de cualquiera" (anybody's patience or any man's patience). He is not referring to humanity as a whole, but as his own patience as a representative of the human race.

Also, `jugar` in this context means "poner a prueba".

> Convenid en que no es posible **jugar con la paciencia humana**.  <sub>Agree that it is not possible to **test people's patience in this way**</sub>